# Verifying a Perceptron Learning Example

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to understand the [perceptron learning algorithm](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K4.pdf) via an example presented by a professor. Here is my understanding. Can any one check If my understanding is correct?

Lets say I have inputs

x1    x2    result(y)

1   3     +1

-1   -2     -1

1    -1     1

-2     1     -1

Now I use the below algorithm to get the weights

w0=0

1)y1(w0x1)<=0

hence w1=w0+y1*x1=[1,3]

2)y2(w1,x2)<=0

hence w2=w1+y2*x2=[3,-1]

3)y3(w2,x2)>=0

hence no iteration

4)y4(w2,x4)<=0

Hence w3=w2+y4*x4=[5,-2]

Hence now my weights are

x1    x2    result(y) weights

1   3     +1           [1,3]

-1   -2     -1         [3,-1]

1    -1     1          [3,-1]

-2     1     -1        [5,2]

Is my understanding right?or am i making mistake with the weights selection /or mistake while making the iteration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you did is correct, but there are a number of comments:

1. You state that, initially, *w0 = 0*. This does not make much sense, as you later add it to vectors of dimension 2. I'm guessing that you meant that *w0 = [0, 0]*.
2. FYI:

   1. A more general perceptron learning algorithm would not add/subtract the misclassified instances, but rather do this for a scaled version multiplied by some *0 < α ≤ 1*. Your algorithm above uses *α = 1*.
   2. It's common to artificially prepend to the perceptron inputs, a constant 1 term. Hence, if the original inputs are vectors of dimension 2, you'd work on vectors with dimension 3, where the first item of each vector is 1.

Comment: Yes w0=[0,0] ,in the process do we find the weights for each data set ,or if we find the weights which are common to all .Ie:in the above example if i calculate weather a weight [3,-1] is applicable to all datasets

Comment: The idea is that you iteratively update the weights: *w0, w1, w2...* one per sample (as you did). Note that you do not necessarily iterate only once over the dataset (in particular, if the learning rate is less than 1). You return the latest *wn* as the final answer.

Comment: Ok got it ,so the output will only be one weight not a combination of weight as i did in the above iteration ,as in the above iteration i though the weights would be [1,3][3,-1][5,-2] etc .Do you have any links where I can learn this with example .As most materials i have provided mathematical but no example .

Comment: Maybe try [this](http://aass.oru.se/~lilien/ml/seminars/2007_02_01b-Janecek-Perceptron.pdf)?

Comment: @asj177 Since you seem relatively new, please note that if an answer addressed your question, you can accept or upvote it.